# how to count records of row SQL in spring mvc and display the number in home page

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working in spring 5 mvc app i have created crud named projet, user can add,edit and delete I want to know how I can to count the number of records in the table "projet" and display the number of projet in dashbord jsp page ??

> Here my dao impl code

[image]

Comment: Which part causes you problem? Running a count query on your database? Calling that query in your DAO? Or displaying a server side value on the frontend?

Comment: how I can calling that query in the DAO

Answer (score 0):

you already have the count via resultset simply put it in a variable in your model then consume it in your jsp page